# Proving the probability triple resulting from the extension theorem is complete

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

One of the exercises in the textbook I'm using for self-study on measure-theoretic probability theory is as follows:

> Prove that the extension $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathbf{P}^*)$ constructed in the proof of [the extension theorem] must be complete, meaning that if $A \in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mathbf{P}^*(A) = 0$, and if $B \subseteq A$, then $B \in \mathcal{M}$.

Some background on definitions first:

- $\mathbf{P}^*$ is defined as the outer measure generated by $\mathbf{P}$ on all the subsets of $\Omega$, and it's been proven that $\mathbf{P}^*$ is monotonic on every subset of $\Omega$.
- $\mathcal{M}$ is, in turn, defined as $\{ A \subseteq \Omega\ \mid\ \forall E \subseteq \Omega : \mathbf{P}^*(E) = \mathbf{P}^*(EA) + \mathbf{P}^*(E \overline{A}) \}$. Since $\mathbf{P}^*$ is proven to be subadditive, we can replace the predicate with $\mathbf{P}^*(E) \geq \mathbf{P}^*(EA) + \mathbf{P}^*(E \overline{A})$ which is sometimes easier to show.

So, here's the proof of the lemma in the exercise:

\begin{align*}
\forall E \subseteq \Omega\ :\ &\mathbf{P}^*(EB) + \mathbf{P}^*(E\overline{B}) \leq \qquad (\text{by monotoniciy and } EB \subseteq B) \\
& \mathbf{P}^*(B) + \mathbf{P}^*(E\overline{B}) \leq \qquad (\text{by monotonicity and } B \subseteq A) \\
& \mathbf{P}^*(A) + \mathbf{P}^*(E\overline{B}) = \qquad (\text{by the lemma condition}) \\
& \mathbf{P}^*(E\overline{B}) \leq \mathbf{P}^*(E) \qquad (\text{by monotonicity and } E\overline{B} \subseteq E).
\end{align*}

So, to sum it up, we have $\forall E \subseteq \Omega : \mathbf{P}^*(E) \geq \mathbf{P}^*(EB) + \mathbf{P}^*(E \overline{B})\quad\blacksquare$

The problem with this proof that I immediately see is that I haven't used the condition of $A \in \mathcal{M}$ (or I truly missed where I used it implicitly). Is it really not necessary, or have I done a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861088

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the Extension Theorem is Complete.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861088/prove-that-the-extension-theorem-is-complete)