# Prove that the Extension Theorem is Complete.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that the probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathbb{P^*}) $ constructed from the Extension Theorem is *complete*.

Specifically, this problem asks us to show that, given any $A \subseteq \Omega$, such that $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $ \mathbb{P^*} (A)=0$, and any $B \subseteq A$, then $$ \mathbb{P^*}(B \cap E) + \mathbb{P^*}(B^c \cap E) = \mathbb{P^*}(E).$$

The proof of this theorem posted below seemed fairly straightforward, but there are two issues (one of which has been previously asked by another user, without answer), which make me doubt it.

The text I am reading writes that, *from this result*, it follows $B$ has outer measure $0$, i.e.:
$$B \in \mathcal{M} \implies \mathbb{P^*}(B)=0,$$ but doesn’t that result follow regardless of whether $B$ is in $\mathcal{M}$ or not?

The other issue is that the following proof does not seem to make use of the fact that $$A \in \mathcal{M}.$$

In fact, it seems we could rewrite the definition of a *complete* probability triple as follows:

**Definition:** If $A \subseteq \Omega$, such that $$\mathbb{P^*}(A)=0,$$ then $$S(A) \in \mathcal{M},$$ where $S(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$.

**Proof:**

By the monitonicity of outer measure, for any $E \subseteq \Omega$, $$\mathbb{P^*}(B \cap E) \leq \mathbb{P^*}(A \cap E).$$

Further, since $(A \cap E) \subseteq A$, $$\mathbb{P^*}(B \cap E)=0. \qquad (1)$$

Clearly, $(B^c \cap E) \subseteq E$, which implies $$\mathbb{P^*}(B^c \cap E) \leq \mathbb{P^*}(E).\qquad (2)$$

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together $$\mathbb{P^*}(B \cap E) + \mathbb{P^*}(B^c \cap E) \leq \mathbb{P^*}(E).$$

Since outer measure is also subadditive: $$ \mathbb{P^*}(E) \leq  
\mathbb{P^*}(B \cap E) + \mathbb{P^*}(B^c \cap E).$$

Thus $\mathbb{P^*}$ is additive on the union $B \cap E$ and $B^c \cap E$, for all subsets $E$ of $\Omega$, from which we conclude $B \in \mathcal{M}$.

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

Any set $A$ with $P^{*}(A)=0$ is measurable. The condition $A \in \mathcal M$ is not necessary.

Comment: Okay, well that’s good. Is there any reason why it was included in the question, then?

Comment: They were just trying state completeness of  $P^{*}$ restricted to the class of measurable sets. This restriction is the main object of interest in analysis. Outer measure is only a tool in the study of measures.

Comment: But what about the Lebesgue measure restricted to $\mathcal{B}$ (the Borel $\sigma$-algebra)? Obviously, there is a subset, say $C \subset A \in \mathcal{B}$ such that the measure on $A$ is zero, where $C$ isn't Borel. Isn't $A \in \mathcal{B}$ necessary in this case, to show completeness (or non-completeness) of measure?

Comment: @119631 Lebesgue on the Borel sigma algebra is not complete.